# Using Telegram API for Java Desktop App?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, api, telegram

I am not that new to Java Programming, but I have never worked with external libraries etc. Now I want to develop a desktop client for the "Telegram" open-source messaging platform, and I'm stuck when it comes to API-Usage.

There is pretty much documentation about the Telegram API, found at https://core.telegram.org/api, and I've already downloaded mtproto, telegram-api and tl-core from github, and compiled my own library jar from source by using gradle. As well, I've already written a small application, where the user clicks a button and is promted to enter his phone number, I'm using the Java-swing-Libraries and an ActionListener for this.

The phone number entered by the user should now be checked if it is already registered, the auth.checkPhone method seems to be capable for that. But how can I refer to it within my eclipse project? I don't see any method "checkPhone" in any of the classes! What should I do?

Please help me, I can't help myself and I am desperately stuck in my project. Even a small hint would help.

Thanks in Advance,
Lukas

Comment: Hi, you can try looking at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903957/starting-a-telegram-api-instance

See if that helps. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Essentially you will have to fill out the blanks in the code given on GitHub in the [ex3ndr/telegram-api](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api) repository. If you've got the library Jar file you built and the `tl-api-v12.jar`file on your Eclipse project's Java build path, then look at the [RPC Calls](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api#rpc-calls) section of the README and

First you need to set up an `AppInfo` object with your [API credentials](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id), then you will also have to create some new classes that implement the `AbsApiState` and `ApiCallback` interfaces. Once these are available, you can create the `TelegramApi` object and make an RPC call to the Telegram service as follows; in this case using the suggested [`auth.checkPhone`](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.checkPhone) method:

```
// TODO set up AbsApiState, AppInfo and ApiCallback objects
TelegramApi api = new TelegramApi(state, appInfo, apiCallback);

// Create request
String phoneNumber = "1234567890";
TLRequestAuthCheckPhone checkPhone = new TLRequestAuthCheckPhone(phoneNumber);

// Call service synchronously
TLCheckedPhone checkedPhone = api.doRpcCall(checkPhone);
boolean invited = checkedPhone.getPhoneInvited();
boolean registered = checkedPhone.getPhoneRegistered();
// TODO process response further
```

The `TelegramApi` object represents your connection to the remote service, which is a request response style of API. RPC calls are made via the `doRpcCall` method, which takes a request object from the `org.telegram.api.requests` package (the `TLRequestAuthCheckPhone` type in the example) filled in with the appropriate parameters. A response object (`TLCheckedPhone` above) is then returned with the result when it is available.

In the case of an asynchronous call the method returns immediately, and the `onResult` callback method is executed when the result is available:

```
// Call service aynchronously
api.doRpcCall(checkPhone, new RpcCallbackEx<TLCheckedPhone>() {
    public void onConfirmed() { }
    public void onResult(TLCheckedPhone result) {
        boolean invited = checkedPhone.getPhoneInvited();
        boolean registered = checkedPhone.getPhoneRegistered();
        // TODO process response further
    }
    public void onError(int errorCode, String message) { }
});
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that it's been a while since my last reply, I gave up working on this project until I saw that someone has answered my old thread. I think, I understood the most of how to get started with this project, but now I'm stuck at the **"apiStorage"**-point. In the readme.md of ex3ndr's-gitHub-page it says, the "Telegram-Api"-Object requires an "ApiStorage"-object, created by **"new MyApiStorage"**. But _I can't find that "MyApiStorage"-class_, so what should I put there?

Comment: Furthermore, I am _unable to build the libraries_ with gradle. I downloaded the resources from GitHub and renamed the folders as told in the readme, but **gradle always fails** with an '* What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':test'. > Configuration with name 'default' not found.' I don't know how to fix this, can you help? Right now I have copied the raw resource files into my eclipse project, but there must be a way to fix that gradle problem. I would appreciate any answers,
Thanks in advance,

Lukas

Comment: The `MyApiStorage` bit is the complicated part. You'll need to make a class that implements the `org.telegram.api.engine.storage.AbsApiState` interface, and use that as the first argument to the constructor. Your IDE should be able to help build a skeleton class to get you started...

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I think I'll give up here, since I don't want to ask you every single step from now on... I can't find any manual that tells me what the methods within my ApiStorage should do, or what any structure in my application should do, and therefore Telegram will have to live without my furious new client... I don't know how to understand all this stuff, if it was explained somewhere, but the API Docs on telegram.org didn't even help me out a single second here... I'm very grateful that you took the time to answer my questions, thanks ;)

Comment: hello grkvlt! i have been able to figure this out but i'm stuck here on how to send and receive messages. please advise how to proceed. LukeLR, check the telegram-bot sample app! it resolves some of these issues of urs!

Comment: Hello, I've read and tried to implement the example given here and unfortunately it doesn't work. It says also that the only thing I have to do is to fullfill the blanks in the example application but id doesn't seem to have any "blanks" to fullfill. The example in command line is in C, so I'm afraid it doesn't match for the cases I need. 
I solved the problem of the AbsApiState, but I get an TimeoutException. Again, it seems that one of these timeouts is caused by Linux (java must use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random), but after that I get another Timeout. Sorry but this is too much for me

Answer (score 0):

Or just look at this API https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api

It is really simple to use

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes