# Starting a Telegram API instance

Tags: cordova, telegram

*Hi! Telegram API beginner here!* I'm developing a PhoneGap app that features a messaging service using the Telegram API.

I'm currently following the API guide and I'm now reading the getting started guide for [authentication](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth). However, I find that it is currently insufficient and not [Jimmy Proof](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).

**How does one create a Telegram API instance in one's  own app? After initialization how does one authenticate a user?** From the link provided, this can be done with the `auth.sendCode` method. But to what class does this method belong to?

Comment: can you guid me how you had create application becuase recenly i am going to create application but it's giving me error i want app id and api_hash

Comment: You can get your app id and api hash from your my.telegram.org page.

Comment: recently u had create new application it giving error it givining only error dialog when cick on create application

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I can understand you. Can you post screenshots or post a separate question regarding your issue?

Comment: it's solve it's api.telegram.org site issue now they can allow to create application

Comment: See my answer here for an example of making RPC calls to the Telegram service - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635355/using-telegram-api-for-java-desktop-app/24472152#24472152

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Referencing some documentation in the [Git Hub page](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api)...*

To create a `TelegramApi` instance, one must first create a custom implementation of the `org.telegram.api.engine.storage.AbsApiState` class and implement the suitable methods. An instance of the custom class implementation will then be used as a parameter for the `TelegramApi` constructor method.

Example from the Git Hub page:

```
TelegramApi api = new TelegramApi(new MyApiStorage(), new AppInfo(/*... put application information here...*/), new ApiCallback()
{
  @Override
  public void onApiDies(TelegramApi api) {
    // When auth key or user authorization dies
  }
  @Override
  public void onUpdatesInvalidated(TelegramApi api) {
    // When api engine expects that update sequence might be broken  
  }
});
```

**As for the `auth.sendCode` method, this method is actually an [remote procedure call (RPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)**, and does not belong to any class in the library. These are methods invoked by the client to be executed by the Telegram server. See the Telegram FAQ regarding [TL](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide I put together [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080) for getting started on writing your own Telegram-API code from scratch *(code is in vb.net)*

I think the online documentation for the API is poorly written, however if you can get familiar with it, then working through generating a **Telegram AuthKey** will be a good starting point.

The patterns and procedures that you build along the way are all reusable and will help you (eventually) write your own code, and have a good understanding of Telegram's API

I think this a good approach.

Cheers.